# Replace Volume Mount for Visual Studio Container Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, docker, containers, visual-studio-2019

My application is a Web API service hosted in a Linux Container.

When I click the "Play" button to start up my application in Visual Studio, one of the options it passes to docker is:

```
-v "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro"
```

I would like to specify my own location:

```
-v ${env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH}:/https/
```

I found the option `DockerfileRunArguments` that I can put in my project file.  And when I do this:

```
<DockerfileRunArguments>-v C:\src\docker_certs:/https/</DockerfileRunArguments>
```

It adds it to the command used to run the file (though I don't know a way to get rid of the one Visual Studio adds in).

However, if I try to use an Environment Variable, it fails with an error due to parsing.

I have tried the following:

- `<DockerfileRunArguments>-v %DOCKER_CERTS_PATH%:/https/</DockerfileRunArguments>`
- `<DockerfileRunArguments>-v $DOCKER_CERTS_PATH:/https/</DockerfileRunArguments>`
- `<DockerfileRunArguments>-v ${DOCKER_CERTS_PATH}:/https/</DockerfileRunArguments>`
- `<DockerfileRunArguments>-v ${env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH}:/https/</DockerfileRunArguments>`

They all give an error.

**Is there anyway to expand an environment variable when passing in this argument?**

Comment: Well, it took me five google searches to land here and learn about `DockerfileRunArguments` so thank you for that. I see what you are trying to do but don't have any suggestions except I was noticing the syntax for variable expansion was different between windows and macOs command lines: [Microsoft Certificate Command Lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: So I immediately needed to do almost the same thing, using the `USERPROFILE` environment variable. The only sucessful variable that can be used that I've seen is `$(pwd)` as shown at [DockerfileRunArguments Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#example). Since that argument is passed as a literal to `docker run` I don't think it can expand it as a host environment variable.